# What is a factory function?

Tags: javascript, oop

I understand that this question may be considered broad. I am currently learning Javascript and throughout the process I've stumbled upon different terms of functions that are thrown around such as: factory function, and constructor functions regarding to object-oriented programming. I am having trouble understanding these terms and finding the distinction among them, although based upon my personal understanding; factory functions are basically regular functions, or am I not seeing the bigger picture in all this? Anyways I hope my brief description of this concept can somehow help in some sort of way.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: "The Factory Function is similar to constructor functions/class functions, but instead of using new to create an object, factory functions simply creates an object and returns it." https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-factory-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor function can be called with the `new` keyword. By calling `new` JavaScript creates a new object and returns this object.

```
let constructorFunction = new IAmConstructorFunction();
```

and its definition:

```
function IAmConstructorFunction() {
   this.foo = "1";
   this.bar = "2";
}
```

A factory function can be called like regular function:

```
let objByFactory = someFactoryFunction();
```

and its definition:

```
function factoryFunction() {
   let obj = {
      foo : "1",
      bar : "2",
      someMethod: function() { 
        /* code of function here */ 
      }
   };      
   return obj;
}
```